# How to deal with follow up questions posted as answers?

Tags: discussion, flagging

I was recently looking through some old questions and stumbled upon a question that was relatively high impact (somewhere around 10k+ views). As such, it has somewhere around four or five answers.

Interestingly, however, the last answer to the question was a follow up question. Clearly, in a strict interpretation, we would flag this as "Not an Answer" and it would likely be deleted. However, this question was clearly germane to the subject at hand, was subsequently upvoted, and ultimately answered by another user.

The difficulty here is that one response would be to flag this "answer" and simply ask the user to ask their question again as a standalone question. The problem with this is that since it is so related to the initial question that was asked, I am not sure that it could survive in isolation. Moreover, there has got to be some benefit to the community by leaving this, if say, the initial answer, while upvoted, was initially not clear or if another user had a similar question. In this sense, the ability to ask a follow up question can have significant utility on the platform. As it currently stands however, this may not be the correct way to do this.

Thoughts? What is the correct action here? Flag for deletion or leave it since it has already been asked and answered a while ago?

This particular case is interesting as it has already been upvoted and answered.

Comment: do you mind sharing the link to that question?

Comment: @oW_ I intentionally omitted  the link so that that the user would not face any negative retribution (ie downvotes), but trusting that others will not do so here it is: https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/13405/what-is-affine-transformation-in-regard-to-neural-networks

Comment: That was a comment.  Also the answer, to the comment, was a comment.

Comment: @StephenRauch they have both since been converted to a comment (perhaps by another Mod). Thank you for looking into this. Also, congrats on Mod for SO.